# Doctrine : UniqueEntity on foreign property?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, foreign-keys

Is it possible to use a UniqueEntity annotation on a foreign object property ?

For example I have two class :

```
class A {
    private $id;
    private $num;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="B" ....)
     */
    private $b;

    ...
}


class B {
    private $id;
    private $sku;

    ...
}
```

I need to prevent users entering a A.num already used for B.sku.
I would like doing something like that :

```
/**
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"num","b.sku"})
 */
class A {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible (like this). If anything, I would expect that you have to make the sku the joinColumn and then mark the relationship on the property b as unique. Even then I don't think it will be quite that easy because if you have multiple entries with the same sku in b and you reference objects via sku I'm not sure Doctrine can safely identify which row to use for this reference.

Comment: Do you want to enforce data integrity on a database level or do you just want to check if your `A` entity is valid by using the [validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html) component of Symfony?

Comment: @AlanT. I Just want to check my A Entity is valid before flushing.

Answer (score 0):

For such a case, you could try to enforce data integrity on a database level but the implementation of such a constraint would mainly depend on your RDBMS ([an exemple here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588072/how-do-i-create-a-multiple-table-check-constraint)). As far as I know, Doctrine only allows to add [unique](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#uniqueconstraint) and [check](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#column) constraints so you will need to trust your application code to validate your entity properly before it is persisted here.

To do so, instead of `UniqueEntity`, you could use the [`Callback`](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/constraints/Callback.html) or the [`Expression`](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/constraints/Expression.html) constraint to create your custom validation rule. Since your rule is not so complex, it would be less verbose to use `@Assert\Expression`. Something like this would produce the desired result:

```
@Assert\Expression(
    "this.getB() == null or this.getB().getSku() != this.getNum()",
    message="The chosen number should not be the same as the associated number B.sku"
)
```

As explained [in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/constraints/Expression.html), you can attach this annotation to your class directly or you can map it to a specific field. In your example, I guess attaching it to `num` would be best.