# Creating a column that only accepts entry when other table's value equals to true

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a small database and need to create a column in `table 1` that will only accept an entry when `table 2` value equals to `true`.

I came up with this code:

```
ALTER TABLE MarshallGroup
ADD TRANumber NUMERIC(4, 0) CHECK (Member.isMarshall = 'True')
```

However, I get this error:

> The multi-part identifier "Member.isMarshall" could not be bound.

I am aware that I have to use inner join but I don't know where to use it (like I said I am new in SQL).

#### EDIT: Here are the tables

```
**First table: Member**     
(PK)TRANumber
firstName
lastName 
gender 
ClubID 
shortNameCatID 
age 
year 
isMarshall <-- this one has to equal to true to be accepted in table 2


**Second Table: MarshallGroup**
(PK)marshallGroupID
(soon to be FK)TRANumber <- this is the column Im creating 
groupNumber
```

Comment: @juergend I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2017

Comment: You cannot add a check constraint that refers to a different table - you can only check for literal values, or for values in the current table. If you really needs this, you have to handle that validation check in a trigger in SQL Server, or in your application logic

Comment: There is a way but it is messy IMO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2588427/575376

Comment: @juergend

First table: Member 

(PK)TRANumber

firstName

lastName

gender

ClubID

shortNameCatID

age

year

isMarshall <-- this one has to equal to true to be accepted in table 2

Second Table: MarshallGroup

(PK)marshallGroupID

(soon to be FK)TRANumber <- this is the column Im creating

groupNumber

Comment: Bloody hell. Sorry for the messy comment. I tried to space it out but it just deletes stuff

Comment: @juergend If I want to limit entries for a specific column, do I have to do it while creating it or can I sort it out after it was created?

Comment: You can do it later: `alter table MarshallGroup add constraint const_name check (...)`

Comment: @juergend Just added both tables to question

Comment: Personally I would handle that check in the program logic and not in SQL.

Comment: @Michael done, found the answer, which is why I deleted it, didnt wanted to bother anyone else. Sorry about that. Looking forward to your answer!

Comment: @Gonper No worries. you can always answer your own question too to share your wisdom :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do what you want with a foreign key constraint and computed column:

```
create table Members as (
    . . .,
    TRANumber number(4, 0),
    isMarshall varchar(10),
    . . .
    constraint chk_members_isMarshall check (isMarshall in ('True', 'False')),
    constraint unq_members_TRANumber_isMarshall unique (TRANumber, isMarshall)
);

create table MarshallGroups as (
    . . .,
    isMarshall as ('True') persisted,
    constraint fk_MarshallGroups_Members
        foreign key (TRANumber, isMarshall) references members(TRANumber, isMarshall)
);
```

The alternatives to this method are either to use a trigger or a user-defined function.