# SQL Server: Constrain Column based on Column in other table

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I'm trying to constrain values of one table based on values from another.  For T1, column 'col' is allowed to be 'A' or 'B'.  For T2 column 'col' is allowed to be 'C' or 'D'.  But T2.col is not allowed to be 'D' if T1.col is 'B'.  They have a many to one relationship of T1.PK = T2.FK. If I try to insert D in T2.col when its joining T1.col = 'B', it should fail.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588072/how-do-i-create-a-multiple-table-check-constraint) but I'm not trying to do any aggregate function.  My current attempt looks like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckAddition()
RETURNS bit
AS BEGIN RETURN (
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN T2.col = 'C' THEN 1
        WHEN T2.col = 'D' AND T1.col = 'A' THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
    END AS 'Check'
    FROM T1 
    INNER JOIN T2
    ON T1.PK = T2.FK
) END

GO;
ALTER TABLE Shift ADD CONSTRAINT checkAdd CHECK (dbo.CheckAddition() = 1);
```

but since it's not an aggregate, I get this failure.

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

*Edit*
My full tables look like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T1](
    [PK] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [col] [char](1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_T1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PK] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_T1] CHECK  (([col]='B' OR [col]='A'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_T1]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T2](
    [PK] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FK] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [col] [char](1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_T2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PK] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T2]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_T2_T1] FOREIGN KEY([FK])
REFERENCES [dbo].[T1] ([PK])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T2] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_T2_T1]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T2]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_T2] CHECK  (([col]='D' OR [col]='C'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T2] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_T2]
GO
```

I'm trying to make it so T2.col can not be 'D', if the matching PK/FK in T1.col = 'A'

Comment: Why not simply use MAX in your function?

Comment: I would probably want Min() or to structure my cases separate, but if the table grows to millions of rows and multiple inserts per second, couldn't that cause a problem if it has to run every time?

Comment: It is absolutely a potential performance issue. But you have a scalar function as a constraint reading two tables seemingly unrelated to the table where the constraint is.

Comment: You function is an scalar function, so, you need to ensure that in all possible scenarios will only return a single value...

Comment: you can use TOP 1 After Select

Comment: @HasanMahmood, that works well as long as I order descending by PK.

Comment: @Faller you are creating a function, I think there are some more condition needed, you just can not check all rows in a function, it might get performance issue, can you please describe your full requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That fix the error you are getting

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckAddition()
RETURNS bit
AS BEGIN 
DECLARE @Res BIT

    SELECT @Res = CASE 
        WHEN T2.col = 'C' THEN 1
        WHEN T2.col = 'D' AND T1.col = 'A' THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
    END 
    FROM T1 
    INNER JOIN T2
    ON T1.PK = T2.FK
    RETURN @Res 
END

GO;
ALTER TABLE Shift ADD CONSTRAINT checkAdd CHECK (dbo.CheckAddition() = 1);
```

But for performance an safety is better to tho this....

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckAddition(@FKValue INT, @Value CHAR(1))
    RETURNS bit
    AS BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Res BIT

        SELECT @Res = CASE 
            WHEN @Value = 'D' AND T1.Col = 'B' THEN 0
            ELSE 1 
        END 
        FROM T1
        WHERE T1.FK = @FKValue
        RETURN @Res 
    END

    GO;

ALTER TABLE T2 ADD CONSTRAINT checkValue CHECK (Col IN ('C','D'));
ALTER TABLE T2 ADD CONSTRAINT checkAdd CHECK (dbo.CheckAddition(FK, Col) = 1);
```

The check runs before inserting the value, so, if your function checks for the commited values, it wont return an error when you are setting a wrong value, but it will when you try to change it to a valid one... 
This way you are sending the values to be validated prior to be inserted...

Comment: Awesome.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using @HasanMahmood's suggestion, this works.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckAddition()
RETURNS bit
AS BEGIN RETURN (
    SELECT TOP 1 CASE 
        WHEN T2.col = 'C' THEN 1
        WHEN T2.col = 'D' AND T1.col = 'A' THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
    END AS 'Check'
    FROM T1 
    INNER JOIN T2
    ON T1.PK = T2.FK
    ORDER BY T2.PK DESC
) END

GO;
ALTER TABLE Shift ADD CONSTRAINT checkAdd CHECK (dbo.CheckAddition() = 1);
```

Comment: It runs, but the way you are using it will return false positives, check my answer