# REFERENCES two different columns in two different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, reference, check-constraints

In a Postgresql database we have a table like below:

```
=# SELECT * FROM toy_cars;
  serial_no |     name
------------+---------------
 199ER276FN | Snow Doctor
 8BE0F79A3R | Flatbed Truck
 D76185CE8G | Sand Speeder

=# SELECT * FROM toy_trains;
    serial_no    |    name
-----------------+-------------
 BMXH5R4T8K7KELD | Howler T140
 B1Q1JJDQW9LQN0G | Quakester
 8HO9240TO6RNNQ9 | Medusa 90

=# SELECT * FROM items_for_sale;
    serial_no    |   in_stock
-----------------+---------------
      199ER276FN | t
 BMXH5R4T8K7KELD | t
 B1Q1JJDQW9LQN0G | f
      8BE0F79A3R | f
 8HO9240TO6RNNQ9 | t
      D76185CE8G | f
```

Note:

- Every `serial_no` column is the primary key of that table and `in_stock` is a boolean.
- `serial_no` in the `toy_cars` table has a regex `CHECK` restraint to allow 10 characters only.
- `serial_no` in the `toy_trains` table has a regex `CHECK` restraint to allow 15 characters only.
- `serial_no` in the `items_for_sale` table is the serial of either the toy cars or trains, and has a regex `CHECK` restraint to allow 10 or 15 characters only.
- All `serial_no` columns have the `UNIQUE` restraint.

We want to add a `REFERENCES` check to `serial_no` in the `items_for_sale` table to make sure that the entered serial is either present in the `toy_cars` table OR the `toy_trains` table.

So, if I were to try `INSERT INTO items_for_sale VALUES('KYVGK0DBYXPMWW8','f');` this would fail because that serial is not present in either `toy_cars` or `toy_trains`.

How can this be done? We prefer to use one table (like it's structured now).

Comment: You might be able to do this with inheritance.  Otherwise, foreign key constraints are not conditional.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you please elaborate? I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you want to check presence of a key in two (other) tables, and you cannot enforce that using foreign key constraints on a single column. Postgres allows you to create `CHECK` expressions for custom checks, but as [the manual says](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS):

> PostgreSQL does not support CHECK constraints that reference table
>   data other than the new or updated row being checked. (...) If
>   possible, use UNIQUE, EXCLUDE, or FOREIGN KEY constraints to express
>   cross-row and cross-table restrictions.
>
> If what you desire is a one-time check against other rows at row
>   insertion, rather than a continuously-maintained consistency
>   guarantee, a custom trigger can be used to implement that.

See [this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27107470/200987) for different solutions.

Some databases (MS SQL Server) allow you to [use a function in `CHECK` expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588072/how-do-i-create-a-multiple-table-check-constraint). That would be optimal, but Postgres does not allow that syntax.

For PostgreSQL, you need to create a [`TRIGGER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtrigger.html) that will execute when something is inserted into `items_for_sale`. That, on the other hand, *does* allow functions or cross-table checks.

It would look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_serial_present
    BEFORE INSERT ON items_for_sale
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION assert_presence_of_serial(); -- implement this function
```

The other linked question also mentions a quite elegant way of achieving this without triggers:

> A clean solution without triggers: add redundant columns and include them in FOREIGN KEY constraints

I quite like this as it's conceptually very simple and easy to grasp. I *think* it would just involve these steps:

1. `ALTER TABLE` to add two columns: `toy_car_serial` and `toy_trains_serial`, both NULLABLE, but with `FOREIGN KEY` constraints on the mentioned tables.
2. Make sure that any `INSERT` will insert a serial into both `serial_no` and `toy_car_serial` OR `serial_no` and `toy_car_serial`.
3. Add `CHECK( toy_car_serial = serial_no OR toy_trains_serial = serial_no)`.

I think two redundant rows and a slight modification to your inserts is a lot less involved than the alternative.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer.

Comment: Would this work instead of using number 3? A friend suggested this: ...`toy_car_serial REFERENCES toy_cars (serial_no)`, ...`toy_train_serial REFERENCES toy_trains (serial_no)`, ....`CHECK(toy_train_serial IS NULL AND toy_car_serial IS NOT NULL OR toy_train_serial IS NOT NULL AND toy_car_serial IS NULL)`

Comment: Yeah, partly. The first part is pretty much the same. But the last part is not enough ... Your check doesn't enforce that _the same_ serial is inserted in the `toy_train_serial` or `toy_car_serial` as in the `serial_no` column. It just checks that not both are set. You can have both, though :-)

Comment: @leetbacoon You could of course also at this point drop the `serial_no` column entirely and just expose a `VIEW` with a `serial_no` that basically selects the value from either of those other two columns. Just rename your table and create a view with the same name and all your existing queries would keep working. Just a suggestion :)